# access indexed data in a loop using R

Tags: r

Lets say I have 5 databases, named `data1`-`data5`. I basically want to create a loop that prints the first 10 rows of the data. In my naïve mind, the code should look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:5){
  print(head(data[i]))
}
```

That does not work. What's the proper way to do this? How do I define `[i]` as the "indexing" variable for the different databases?

Comment: The situation here seems similar to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use `get` function:

```r
for (i in 1:5){
  tmp <- get(paste0("data", i))  
  ## Assigns the data to the variable tmp - just like tmp <- data1/data2/data3 etc
  print(head(tmp))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to put these objects in a list and use `[[` to reference them.  But if you must use separate names for the objects, then you need to *parse* them and *evaluate* the resulting *expressions*.

Here's an example you can emulate.  For brevity, it prints the values of numerical objects rather than the heads of "databases."

```
data1 <- 1; data2 <- 2; data3 <- 3
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(eval(parse(text=paste0("data", i))))
}
```